# $|x_{n + 1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{2^n} \Rightarrow (x_n)$ is Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence with the property that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$|x_{n + 1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{2^n}$$
I want to show, using the definition of a Cauchy sequence, that $(x_n)$ must be Cauchy.

I have found that the property implies that for any $(m, n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, assuming without loss of generality that $m > n$, it must be true that
$$|x_n - x_m| \leq \sum\limits_{i = n}^m \frac{1}{2^i}$$

How can I proceed from there ? Is this even the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: What is $k$, and how you got this inequality? Substituting $n = m + 1$ you get $x_n - x_m| < 0$ that can't be right.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683023/42969

Comment: Fixed my question, thank you. I get this result by repeatedly applying the triangle inequality. I will go and check out this possible duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly different argument which is not presented on the linked duplicates:

- $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - x_{k-1}) = x_n - x_0$ is (absolutely) convergent
- $\Rightarrow x_n = s_n + x_0$ is convergent
- convergent sequences are Cauchy-sequences

Comment: You can always add another answer to the possible duplicate target (and vote to close). That is preferred (as I understand it) because the various solutions are kept in a single place.

Comment: Btw, this only “hides” the triangle-inequality argument in the conclusion $\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_k - x_{k-1}|$ convergent $\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - x_{k-1})$ convergent (and uses the Cauchy criterion, which is not needed to answer the original question).

Comment: @MartinR : I wouldn't call it "hiding". It is just using known basic facts and, that way, avoiding to repeat some standard calculations. And btw., I wrote "... slightly different ..." in my introductory sentence. :-)